# Reference material for stochastic processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, soft-question

I am interested in reference material for [Physical Applications of Stochastic Processes](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbMVogVj5nJQo8D9D-D6lMqh4FJbPeE_f). The playlist does have an associated [book](https://www.amazon.in/Mathematical-Physics-Applications-Problems-Balakrishnan/dp/3030396827), but it is a litte dense, and the derivations are mostly left to the exercises.
Is there any book/site that covers the same material (a different perspective), or even one on general stochastic processes.